# Cordova and ionic 1 deploys as static files. Can I deploy as server?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

When I write in console:

```
ionic serve
```

It starts local server at port 8100 and my OpenID Connect authentication login flow works, but when I start:

```
ionic prepare ios
```

And start project from XCode, my JavaScript's `window.location.href` has value `file:///Users....` instead of `http://localhost:8100/`

Is there any solution for that ? or it can't be solved by design ?

Answer (score 0):

To serve via localhost:

1. Install plugins:

   - `cocoon-cordova-labs-local-webserver`
   - `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine`
2. In `config.xml` add

   `<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
       <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
   </feature>
   <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />`

After the plugin is installed, it changes the `config.xml` in your project root by modifying this tag to:

```
<content src="http://localhost:0" />
```

For the local web server to start, the url must be `http://localhost`, and you can set the port to whatever you want in the url, the local web server will use this as the port automatically. If you set the port to "0", it will select a randomized and free port.

If you plan on using HTML5 localStorage and/or IndexedDB, you must choose a fixed port in the content tag specified above. This is because of the HTML5 Origin policy (scheme, domain and port must be the same).

In the config.xml in your project root, change the '0' port to a number between 1 and 49152 (avoiding the ephemeral port range of 49152 to 65535 on iOS). For example:

```
<content src="http://localhost:49000" />
```

This port number must be consistent across all app launches for saved data to be accessed.